# Moving absolute positioned resize icons with the rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I've a rectangle and when I'm dragging, I want the resizer icons move together. I set each of 4 resizer icons absolute position and using `mousemove` event and setting `top,` `left` positions on each movement.

[screenshot of rectangle with resizers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NgUX.png)

But it seems to laggy, what are other options to do this?

```
    // I used useRef for referencing resizer icons. 

    resize1.current.style.top = top - 10 + "px";
    resize1.current.style.left = left - 10 + "px";
    resize1.current.hidden = false;

    resize3.current.style.top = top - 10 + "px";
    resize3.current.style.left = left + offsetWidth + "px";
    resize3.current.hidden = false;

    resize5.current.style.top = top + offsetHeight + "px";
    resize5.current.style.left = left + offsetWidth + "px";
    resize5.current.hidden = false;

    resize7.current.style.top = top + offsetHeight + "px";
    resize7.current.style.left = left - 10 + "px";
    resize7.current.hidden = false;
```

Comment: Could you please show your entire code?

Comment: Okay, but the question here is I'm changing the `top` and `left` property of every resize icon to the same as moving rectangle on mouse move event. Is that good idea?

Comment: I don't  think it is, if it can be done using only css `psuedoelements`

Comment: Could you please show me an example?

Comment: Please see this https://jsbin.com/yavarewico/1/edit?html,css,output, let me know if it helps

Comment: Its laggy because you are changing the dom 12 times with all your statements above. Are those elements positioned absolutely? Do you have a codesandbox example?

Comment: Yes all elements positioned absolutely, Okay I'll let you know when I create an sandbox example

Comment: @chintuyadavsara I want to show resize icons only when rectangle is clicked and moving.

Comment: How do you think about add another container for rectangle?